# Implementing the double-click event on Silverlight 4 Datagrid

Tags: events, silverlight-4.0

Any good soul have an example of implementing the "Command Pattern" introduced by Prism on a double click event in a Silverlight 4.0 DataGrid?

I tried the following:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgUserRoles" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedUser.UserRoles}" IsReadOnly="False">
    <data:DataGrid.Columns>
        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Click="Button_Click" Command="{Binding EditRoleClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedRole}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Role Name" Binding="{Binding RoleName}" />
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Role Code" Binding="{Binding UserroleCode}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="UDFM Managed" Binding="{Binding RoleIsManaged}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="UDFM Role Assigned" Binding="{Binding UserroleIsUdfmRoleAssignment}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Source User" Binding="{Binding SourceUser}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
</data:DataGrid>
```

As you see I did try to hook up the Command there and it is not firing the event in my View Model.

Looking for a good alternative.

Comment: I don't see any double-click code in here.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this, whats the best way to implement double clicks?

Answer (score 0):

First, Button.Command is not for double-click. It will work with single click as well.

You need to change like that. **ElementName=dgUserRoles, Path=DataContext.**

```
 Command="{Binding ElementName=dgUserRoles, Path=DataContext.EditRoleClickedCommand}"
```